# How to send hyperlink with mailR?

Tags: r, email, hyperlink

Example code:

```
library(mailR)

path='/Users/me/Downloads/file.xlsx'

send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = 'email with hyperlink',
          body = c(path),
          html = FALSE,
          inline = FALSE,
          smtp = list(host.name = a, port = b, 
                      user.name = c,            
                      passwd = d, ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to display the path as a hyperlink in the body of the email?

Comment: Try `html = TRUE` :)

Comment: @daroczig: Thanks, for the url case it worked! I just edited the example: I would actually like to generate a hyperlink that links to a certain folder location.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: you want to add a link to a local file? How will the recipient be able to access that from a remote machine? Why not add that Excel spreadsheet to the e-mail as attachment or make the file available via a webserver so that you can link to it?

Comment: Thank you. I will probably just send it as an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example:

```
library(mailR)

path="file:///C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\file.xlsx"

send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = 'email with hyperlink',
          body = path,
          html = FALSE,
          inline = FALSE,
          smtp = list(host.name = a, port = b, 
                      user.name = c,            
                      passwd = d, ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Comment: sorry if it was unclear; if you format the 'path' with 'file:///...' and use double backslashes in the rest; '\\' then the body of the email will automatically hyperlink. Does that answer the question?